# WooCommerce custom out of stock text + specific product id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Here is what I am trying to do

1. Detect if a specific product is in stock
2. If yes, edit the custom stock message
3. display a custom message above the A2C button (where stock quantity notification is)

Problem: ALL products are at the moment being edited. I am not successfully applying it do specific product IDs.

**This is what I tried so far**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    global $product;

    // custom 
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() && $product_id = '6498' ) {
        $availability['availability'] = sprintf( __('&#10004;&#65039; Available but low in stock | 30-day No Questions Asked Money-Back Guarantee Applies', 'woocommerce'), $product->get_stock_quantity());
    }

    // Out of stock
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sorry, All sold out!', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $availability;
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 10, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) { 
    // custom 
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() && $_product->get_id() == '6498' ) {
        $availability['availability'] = sprintf( __('&#10004;&#65039; Available but low in stock | 30-day No Questions Asked Money-Back Guarantee Applies', 'woocommerce'), $_product->get_stock_quantity());
    }

    // Out of stock
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sorry, All sold out!', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but in fact this ended up breaking the product page.